# How to require dependency file only after initializing the plugin?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to require `bootstrap-datepicker` plugin with localization.
In my module I have dependency:

```
define(
    ['bootstrap-datepicker-ru'],
    function(){}
)
...
```

In RequireJ config I set path:

```
paths: {
    'bootstrap-datepicker-ru': 'libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.ru',
    ...
}
```

And shim:

```
shim: {
    'bootstrap-datepicker-ru':{
        deps: ['libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker'],
    },
    ...
}
```

So I expect that the `bootstrap-datepicker.js` file will be loaded first, since it is listed in the dependencies (`deps`), and then the `bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js`.

But I get the following error:

`Cannot read property 'dates' of undefined bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js`

I don't understand why I got this error. At the time assignment `$.fn.datepicker.dates` in localization file, `$.fn.datepicker.dates` must already exist.

Comment: The config you show looks fine. Did you check in the debugging tools what loads and what does not?

Comment: @Louis in network tab both files are loaded.